# Php não recebe os dados que passo com $http.post do angular

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

Olá, pessoal. Estou tentando receber uns dados que são passados pelo $http.post para um script php. Este é o meu ajax com angular:

```
    $http.post('../_classes/chamaOddss.php', id).then(function(datae) {
        console.log(datae);
    });
```

Este é meu script php que uso para receber esses dados:

```
$jogoId = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $jogoId;
```

o

> console.log(datae)

mostra isso:

> Object {data: "null", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

Podem me ajudar? Obrigado!

Comment: Não é esse?
    $http.post('../_classes/chamaOddss.php', id).then(function(datae) {
        console.log(datae);
    });

Comment: Confusão minha, quis dizer que é pra mostrar o *payload* que está sendo enviado.

Comment: Desculpa, acho que não entendi o que você está pedindo. Se quiser saber a informação que estou mandando é apenas um id, de três a sete algarismos, exemplo: 689574.